# Query Selector not returning expected result

Tags: c#, web-scraping, anglesharp

I am testing AngleSharp but dont have any experience with this library. I am trying to find all links with class sec:

I am looking for the link in following element:

```
<a href=""https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/fr/cp0/e15/q65/67715124_2371790876231157_8525962613199208448_o.jpg?_nc_cat=103&amp;_nc_oc=AQkThCBAoB0I_2XHh4u-qr7hadhDlS0Dg2ECZNIe550HyD-A6ezCh_QZjuEQx220aSc&amp;_nc_ht=scontent-arn2-1.xx&amp;oh=71d2e150fa02bd1d076aca047d32f3c4&amp;oe=5DD0C8D7"" target=""_blank"" class=""sec"">
```

Code:

```
var htmlSnip = @"<div class=""hidden_elem""><code id=""u_0_o""><!-- <div class=""_2vj7 _2phz voice acw"" data-ft=""&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;,g&quot;&#125;"" data-sigil=""marea""><div class=""_7om2""><div class=""_4g34""><div class=""ib""><a class=""darkTouch l"" href=""/KotaSchuetz/?__tn__=%2Cg"" aria-hidden=""true""><i class=""img profpic"" aria-label=""Dakota Schuetz"" role=""img"" style=""background:#d8dce6 url(&#039;https\\3a //scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/cp0/e15/q65/p40x40/13124828_1029085033835088_7844361004412130142_n.jpg?_nc_cat\\3d 109\\26 _nc_oc\\3d AQm_JxPL6YZp2kJuVkP3xtMVjLsJnjqyjI1jlfYXOQoSs850c9q4UNK4BDWHhE7dSpI\\26 _nc_ht\\3d scontent-arn2-1.xx\\26 oh\\3d 175656024282a65c450bc5cbe3bd18a0\\26 oe\\3d 5DECDD43&#039;) no-repeat center;background-size:100% 100%;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%;width:40px;height:40px;"" data-sigil=""touchable""></i></a><div class=""c""><div class=""msg""><a href=""/KotaSchuetz/?__tn__=%2Cg"" class=""actor-link"" data-sigil=""actor-link""><strong class=""actor"">Dakota Schuetz</strong></a><br /><div class="""">Canâ€™t wait for &#064;fuelfest in the UK tomorrow! Over 700 cars<div id=""voice_replace_id"" class=""""></div></div></div><div class=""desc attachment mfss""><span class=""fcg""><div class=""atb""><div class=""_2vja mfss fcg""><a href=""/KotaSchuetz/albums/240007859409480/?__tn__=%2Cg"" class=""
"">Tidslinjebilleder</a><span aria-hidden=""true""> Â· </span><abbr data-store=""&#123;&quot;time&quot;:1565432522,&quot;short&quot;:false,&quot;forceseconds&quot;:false&#125;"" data-sigil=""timestamp"">for 4 timer siden</abbr><span aria-hidden=""true""> Â· </span><i class=""feedAudienceIcon img sp_EXjamvPof_c sx_76456f"" aria-label=""Offentligt"" role=""img""></i></div><span class=""_2vja mfss fcg""><a href=""https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/fr/cp0/e15/q65/67715124_2371790876231157_8525962613199208448_o.jpg?_nc_cat=103&amp;_nc_oc=AQkThCBAoB0I_2XHh4u-qr7hadhDlS0Dg2ECZNIe550HyD-A6ezCh_QZjuEQx220aSc&amp;_nc_ht=scontent-arn2-1.xx&amp;oh=71d2e150fa02bd1d076aca047d32f3c4&amp;oe=5DD0C8D7"" target=""_blank"" class=""sec"">Vis fuld stÃ¸rrelse</a></span></div></span></div></div></div></div><div class=""_5s61""></div></div></div><div data-sigil=""m-mentions-expand""><footer><div class=""_2ip_ _4b44 _5187"" data-sigil=""mufi-inline""></div></footer></div> --></code></div>
";
var docSnip = context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(htmlSnip)).Result;
var linksLinq = docSnip.All.Where(m => m.LocalName == "a" && m.ClassList.Contains("sec"));
var linksQuery = docSnip.QuerySelectorAll("a.sec").ToList();
```

Am I doing anything wrong here or is library not working?

Comment: Based on the sample code (https://anglesharp.github.io/docs/Examples.html), you should get rid of the .Result from var docSnip = context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(htmlSnip)).Result;

Comment: Why should that have an impact? Whether i do await or result shouldnt change result? The document is loaded as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. Most of the html is within a comment.